# How to avoid unnecessary cast when declaring a generic type parameter with two interfaces

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

Why do I have to explicitly cast command to C in the following code?
Commands implements both Runnable and Describable.

```
@Test
public <C extends Runnable & Describable> void testMapOfCommands() throws Exception
{
    Map<String, C> commands = Maps.newHashMap();
    for(Commands command : Commands.values())
    {
        commands.put(command.name(), (C) command);
    }
    //Use commands here (not relevant to my question):
    //CommandLineParser.withCommands(commands).parse("commit");
}

private enum Commands implements Runnable, Describable
{
    commit
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("COMMIT");
        }

        @Override
        public String description()
        {
            return "Commits something";
        }
    };
}
```

One workaround I have in mind is to introduce ICommand that extends both Runnable and Describable:

```
public interface ICommand extends Runnable, Describable{}
```

but I'm trying to avoid having to introduce a new type when there already is two types readily available and I already have a Command class that's a bit more complex. Am I grasping for straws here?

Comment: First, please post the entire class. Second, you need to use implements, not extends, for interfaces like Runnable.

Comment: Updated the code a bit, I think all relevant code is posted. What parts are you missing?

Comment: @Antimony: nope. In generic types, extends is used. Not implements. Even with interfaces.

Comment: Given your code, you'll get a ClassCastException if you ever invoke the generic method with any generic type other than Commands. If I create a class Foo that implements both interfaces, and call `yourObject.<Foo>testMapOfCommands()`, it won't work. I don't understand why your method is generic, especially if it's a unit test method.

Comment: I was trying to use Map<String, Runnable & Describable> but couldn't get it to work without declaring C.

Comment: It will work without a ClassCastException, any class implementing both Runnable and Describable is castable to C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is a `command` object that is of type `Commands`.  But because of your generic type declaration `<C extends Runnable & Describable>`, Java expects `C` to be both `Describable` and `Runnable`, but `C` is not necessariy a `Commands`.

This particular test method isn't meant to work with anything but `Commands`, so it should not be generic.  This should work:

```
public void testMapOfCommands() throws Exception
{
    Map<String, Commands> commands = new HashMap<String, Commands>();
    for(Commands command : Commands.values())
    {
        commands.put(command.name(), command);
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked! thanks. I would however appreciate it if I could understand why the compiler can't cast Commands to a Runnable & Describable. My code worked as well, just that it was a bit weird with the (C)command cast.

Comment: The Java compiler thinks that C could be _anything_ that implements both `Runnable` and `Describable`, even if it's a `Commands2`, that happens to be both `Describable` and `Runnable` too.  So it disallows the parameter of type `Commands`, because you shouldn't be able to put a `Commands` into something that could be a `HashMap<String, Commands2>` (even if we know it really isn't).

Comment: Aah, so it's because the compiler can't figure out that I only want the Runnable & Describable part of Commands.

Comment: Java's type system really isn't strong enough to do much messing around with "intersection types" like that.